# Fluid Container in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make fluid container in bootstrap 3?

In bootstrap 2.3.2 `.container-fluid` class is there. But now in bootstrap 3 it is missing and there is only `.container` class. Please help me.

Comment: Don't use `.container` just begin with a `.row`>`.col-*-n` (`.container-fluid` is redundant to a `.row`)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 In other words, is using Bootstraps 2.3.2's fluid behaviour as *default* for it's column structures.

Comment: @BradChristie wouldn't leaving out the .container make the contents of the row start all the way to the left (when viewing on md or lg), vs having some padding on the left and right?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bootstrap **3.0** moved to a "mobile first" approach. `.container` is really only there in instances where you need/want a boxy layout. but, if you exempt the `div.container-fluid` entirely, you're left with a fluid layout by default.

for example, to have a two-column fluid layout, simply use:

```
<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <div style="padding:0 15px;"><!-- offset row negative padding -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a tip, row negative padding is there to match col padding

Comment: bad answer. `.container-fluid` *is* what you call “offset row negative padding”, just more semantically. so people: use `class="container-fluid"` instead of `style="padding:0 15px;"`.

Comment: @flyingsheep: Keep in mind I wrote this pre-v3.1 where they re-added `.container-fluid`.

Comment: well, you do mention it, though :)

Answer (score 21):

The 2.x `.container-fluid` was replaced by `.container` in Bootstrap 3.x (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration), so the `.container` *is fluid*, but it's not full width.

You can use the `row` as a fluid container, but you must tweak it a little to avoid a horizontal scroll bar. Excerpt from the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

> "Folks looking to create fully fluid
>   layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport)
>   must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0
>   15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows."

More on changes in 3.x: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Demo: http://bootply.com/91948

**UPDATE for Bootstrap 3.1**

`container-fluid` has returned again in Bootstrap 3.1. Now `container-fluid` can be used to create a full width layout: http://www.bootply.com/116382

Comment: "container-fluid has returned again in Bootstrap 3.1" - this is confusing! How is container-fluid different from no container at all?

Comment: [See the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding"

Answer (score 13):

This was introduced in v3.1.0: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Commit [#62736046](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/6273604601c58284f49b38ae4e52533b9689437c) added ".container-fluid variation for full-width containers and layouts".

Answer (score 4):

I simply setup the following CSS rule where any row that is a child of container-fluid will no longer have a negative margin that offsets the grid system.

```
.container-fluid > .row {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I will test further to see if this creates any issues with other fixed width grid layouts.

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers here, so I will try to avoid my self repeating with my following points on the subject:

1. .container-fluid was removed in 3.0 but now it's back in 3.4  (this info is in reply but I wanted to put it on answer)
2. To get latest version go **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)** or use Nuget.
3. Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
4. For latest info on Container please go **[here for Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**