# Layout issue when updating twitter-bootstrap from 3.0.0 to 3.1.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website that uses twitter-bootstrap for responsive layout. I upgraded from version 3.0.0 to 3.1.1 and my layout has changed and I can't figure out why.

Here's some simplified JSFiddles that show the issue:

### [JSFiddle - Working with 3.0.0](http://jsfiddle.net/58DaR/)

### [JSFiddle - Failing with 3.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/58DaR/1/)

The only difference in these fiddles is the bootstrap version. I've reviewed the [**releases**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases), but can't see anything obvious that has caused this issue.

Apologies for the amount of code/css, I've tried to trim it down to the bare minimum.

**My Markup:**

```
<div class="body-panel container">
    <div class="container header">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 716px;">
                     <h1>Header logo</h1>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default container center">        
        <div class="container navbar-inner">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content grey-panel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="container col-sm-12 home-bg">
                        <div class="container col-sm-5">
                             <h1>Header Text</h1>

                            <p>Some Content:</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Custom Css:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #ABC6A3;
}
.body-panel {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 345px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    /* ie7 fix */
    *zoom: 1;
    /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
.header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.grey-panel {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because they reintroduced the `.container-fluid` class (it was taken out initially, then put back in following feedback).  After reintroducing it, rather than setting `max-width` on the `.container` class, they set explicit widths according to the media query.

In the blog entry here http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/02/13/bootstrap-3-1-1-released/ they say:

> Remove manual full-width container callout now that there's .container-fluid

Your layout works if you replace your `<div class="container>` with `<div class="container-fluid>`.

I would say that you have a number of `container` classes that you don't need.  Your HTML could be trimmed massively:  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/58DaR/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to figure out the issue, mainly from creating and looking at the simplified JSFiddles above.

The issue is with my use of the `.container` class, which I have now replaced with `.container-fluid` and the issue goes away.

### [JSFiddle - Working with 3.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/58DaR/2/)

The answers to the below question may help future users that stumble across the same issue as I had:

**[bootstrap 3.1 container-fluid vs container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263969/57475)**

Answer (score 1):

You are using the class `container` far to often when it is possibly not needed, or could even be replaced with `container-fluid`.

Having that much padding everywhere could limit your space within the main parent.

Only use `container-fluid` or `container` when necessary. The following statement is taken directly from the [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) page:

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Try just having `container` on your main div (most parent wrapper) to make it a fixed width, and either removing `container` from your child divs to make them fluid within their parent, or giving them `container-fluid` to make them have a `max-width: 100%` along with some extra padding.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/58DaR/5/)

Comment: If I stretch the output panel the header logo disappears?

Comment: Wow, that's an odd issue haha. One sec, I'll see what's going on.