# Bootstrap grid system not properly displaying with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create two columns: one for my sidebar and one for the main content but rather than appearing side-by-side, one is appearing beneath the other and overlapping as I add content.

`<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="sideNavContents" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="bodyContents" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>`

Comment: the css and the bootstrap did not have nothing to do with asp.net, not even know that exist - Did the css load ? all the html struct is ok ?

Comment: It appears to be all correct just the columns aren't next to each other as I want it but beneath.

Comment: You need to look into `container-fluid` and [what it means](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22263828/304683)...

Comment: Bootstrap place them the one under the other when did not have space, try to set fluid also on the row, the fluid did not let him go down, but side. If you have it online somewhere to test it I can help you more. Also you use the 12 grid full size, try the second column to be smaller, eg from col-sm-9 -> col-sm-7 and see if works. If works then is the fluid that needs or not needs...

Comment: I tried setting row fluid and making the second one the smaller column and neither solutions worked