# Bootstrap 3 gridsystem align navbar menu with pagecontent & set the pagecotent size

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem with aligning the navbarmenu with the pagecontent so it fits herizonal perfect. Right now it looks like this picture:

[image]

As you can see i want the page content be 950px (white space) and the grey outside is an overall background-color. I have only tried to create fullsize pages, so is this the right way to do it, with the width: 950px;? or is there a smarter way to force it to 950px at fullscreen for all pages?

What i'm trying to do, is to make it look like this page (the layout):

[image]

You can see fullsize page at: [This page](https://www.komplett.dk/)

**As you can see** the navbarmenu fits and a aligned with the page content and even if you try to resize it.

**Code (_Layout):**

```
 <body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbarunder">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

**CSS file:**

```
 .indexpage {
background-color: white;    
height: 500px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

 @media (min-width: 1000px) {
.indexpage {
    width: 950px;
}
}

 .navbar-inverse {
background-color: white;
border-width: 0px;
border-bottom: thin solid #95a5a6;

}

.navbarunder {
font-variant: small-caps;
border-top: thick solid #003665;
border-width: 8px;
}
```

Hope someone can tell me what i should look at, because i have tried everything what i know..

Answer (score 0):

I believe `container-fluid` on your navigation `div` is the culprit, as discussed in the accepted answer to [Container-fluid vs .container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container)

You might want to consider using one of the Bootstrap examples like [Sticky Footer Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). View source on that page and you can grab the parts you want and begin tweaking that HTML to fit your needs.

Comment: Well i already knew it could be done like this.. but if i want the page content size to be fixed width = 950px? I want to remove the resize of the page untill it actually should go in ipad mode.