# Moving header to the left, can't seem to figure it out? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

This will be an easy question for most of you no doubt. I am trying to make a web page for my friend using this theme:

http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_452_stone

I'm trying to move the header "STONE" more to the left, any ideas on how to do this?.. Also if possible I'd like the front-page image to be slightly higher up than it is.

Thanks in advance, I've got a headache from all the messing with it!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your .container class has a set width of 1177px. If you only want the header to move and not the links as well, then you'll have to add some negative margin.

```
.navbar-header {
   margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change your class `container` to `container-fluid` as below.**

```
<div class="site-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
```

The final output would be as below.

[image]

The difference between `container` and `container-fluid` as stated in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638864/3168859) is

> .container-fluid continuously resizes as you change the width of your
>   window/browser by any amount, leaving no extra empty space on the
>   sides ever, unlike how .container does. (Hence the naming: "fluid" as
>   opposed to "digital", "discrete", "chunked", or "quantized").

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Thankyou ... :) @HunterTurner

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this css rule to achive it:

```
div.row {
    margin-left: -100px !important;
}
```

But as I don't know about your html/css structure it may have side effects...

You can also search in the html for the line:

```
<div class="row">
```

and put the style inlined:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: -100px">
```

Of course change -100px for the number of pixels you want. In the original css it's set to -15px;