# What is the difference between bootstrap "container-fluid" and "container-full"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

What is the difference between bootstrap `container-fluid` and `container-full`?

Comment: I think if you see this page you will get your answer. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Do you mean container-fluid and container?

Answer (score 1):

Fluid has max-width. Container-full doesn't.