# Bootstrap 3 Half background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align TEXT of container-fluid at same padding/margin like container.
You have example in this image:

---

EDIT: See 2nd photo, i want that padding to be the same on container-fluid / container, and when you minimize screen to be responsive..

[image] 
[image]

```css
.nopadding {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.left {
  height: 650px;
}

.img-bg {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  height: 650px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/850x650) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <section id="id1">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-7 nopadding bg">
                <div class="left">
                      <h2>TEXT</h2>
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-md-5 nopadding img-bg">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

HTML part:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text no-padding center-flex">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 image no-padding">
      <div class="full-width"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text no-padding center-flex">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text no-padding center-flex">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text no-padding center-flex">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text no-padding center-flex">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.center-flex {
  /* Internet Explorer 10 */
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  /* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;
  /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  /* W3C */
  display:box;
  box-pack:center;
  box-align:center;
}

.container-fluid .text {
  background: #515467;
  height: 650px;
}

.container .text {
  background: #737373;
  height: 300px;
}

.container-fluid .image {
  background: #2D2D2D;
  height: 650px;
}

.full-width {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/850x650');
  background-size:cover;
}

.full-width img {
  width:100%;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.no-margin {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

You can see the jsfiddle result: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18725/

Comment: Text from container-fluid needs to be aligned same like container, http://i.imgur.com/t2H5tc2.jpg

Comment: @Razvan I am sorry but the first version of your question was directly the same with my solution and you are forcing me to solve new challenges.. In addition, '.container-fluid' continuously resizes as you change the width of your window/browser by any amount, leaving no extra empty space on the sides ever, unlike how .container does. '.container' resizes in chunks at several certain widths. In other words, it will be a specific aka "fixed" width at different screen widths. Therefore, you can only align them in same position for some specific resolutions according to '.container'.

Comment: To learn more, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you

```css
.text1{
  background : #0f74bd;
  padding : 50px;
  color : white;
  font-weight : bold;
}

.image{
  background : #000;
  padding : 50px;
  color : white;
  font-weight : bold;
}
.text{
  background : #9ea3a9;
  padding : 50px;
  color : white;
  font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text1">
        TEXT1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 image">
        IMAGE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container text">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        TEXT2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        TEXT3
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        TEXT2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        TEXT3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</section>
```

Comment: If you have screen resolution 1920x1080

Comment: can you post image of that screen where it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title> 
</head>
<body> 
<div style="background-color: blue" class="container-fluid">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Container-Fluid</h1>
  <div class="row">
   <div  style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">TEXT 1</div>
   <div  style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">IMAGE</div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="background-color: yellow" class="container">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Container</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">Text 1</div>
      <div style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">Text 2</div>
      <div style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">Text 3</div>
      <div style="text-align:center" class="col-xs-6">Text 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what u want, using bootstrap