# If I use .container-fluid in Bootstrap 3, does that mean I need to use grid classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read several of the SO answers to what `.container` and `.container-fluid` are, but what I am missing is simple.  Do I use column classes like col-xs-6, col-md-9, etc., if I am using .container-fluid?  Both resize and .container does it specific sizes, which is why I use the col-x-x classes, but .container-fluid resizes everything all the time, so does .container-fluid take care of the column sizing automatically and I "trust" it gets it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `container-fluid` is used to [contain the grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) (`row` + `col-*`) but can be used for other things such as headings, tables, etc..

So no, `container-fluid` is not a replacement for columns, it's a holder of columns. The only difference between `container-fluid` and `container` is that the `container` is *not* full-width on larger screens. The `container` is a fixed width that's centered with large margins on the sides. `container-fluid` doesn't resize, it's always 100% width. [Container demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/8YUeh6gIk0)

If you want to use the responsive grid (rows and columns), you need to use container or container-fluid like this..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        (one or more col-*-* here)
    </div>
</div>
```

*Or*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        (one or more col-*-* here)
    </div>
</div>
```

Read [this article](https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc) for a complete explanation.

Comment: But how does it handle the columns at the different sizes?  I trust it?  That the documentation I am guessing.

Comment: `container-fluid` doesn't really "handle" the columns any differently. The columns handle their own width/resizing. However if you consider that `col-md-4` is a 33% width column, 33% of full width (`container-fluid`) will obviously be wider than 33% of a fixed width (`container`) on larger screens.

Comment: So I really do not need the col classes in container-fluid?

Comment: No. If you're using the grid (row + col's) you use either `container` or `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 1):

Containers exist mostly to 1) limit page width and 2) provide padding for rows. Fluid containers only do the latter. If you aren't using rows, you may not need containers. However, if you're using columns you should be using rows and containers for better, more controllable structure.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can because the `.container-fluid` is used as `container` but the difference is in responsive sizes.

see: [Container-fluid vs .container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Visit the help center to learn how to write a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks.