# CSS background does not fill all page properly when scrolled horizontally

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

So, I am new to HTML CSS and in progress in designing a website. I am designing a website which is similar to trello (https://trello.com). Where you can add cards, delete cards, etc.

I have this background problem where the background does not cover the whole page when I scrolled horizontally,

Here is the problem I have:

[image: The webpage]

As you can see, the whole page looks okay, the background works properly. However, If I added more list, the background does not works properly.

[image: The webpage 2]

[image: The webpage 3]

Here, the background is white when I scrolled horizontally. It does not cover the whole page.

Here is my Html code:

```
<div class="container" id="amethystBackground2">
    <!-- contents here -->  
</div>
```

Here is my Css code:

```
#amethystBackground2
{ 
    position: relative;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
   //This is needed to remove white space on top of page
    margin: 30px 0 0 0; 
   //This is needed to for the background cover the whole page when scrolled verticallly 
    //(when you have too much cards, you need to scroll down)
    min-height: 100vh; 
    min-width: 100vw;
    //This is needed give space on top of page
    margin: 50px 0 0 0; 

}
```

I tried adding `overflow-x: hidden` and it is just not allowing me to scroll horizontally which is not helpful.

I also tried `width:100%` and 'height:100%', But it does not work.

Please help me, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.container` class of Bootstrap as a size in pixels, so it won't fit the whole page if you extend it.

---

**First solution**

Set your `background-color` to your **`body` instead of your `container div`**.

Just move `background-color:#9B59B6` to

```
body {
    background-color:#9B59B6;
}
```

---

**Second solution**

The *"Bootstrapest way"* would probably be using a `container-fluid` instead of a container, because it can expands to fill the available width.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="amethystBackground2">
    <!-- contents here -->  
</div>
```

*More about container-fluid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container).*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. But I am developing this on ASP.net. so there is no body tag, just the div tag. Can I add body tag to this?? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Look at my second solution ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it does not work well. I tried changing the 'width: 100wh' to 'width: 150wh' and it works. However, people told me not to use that kind of approach.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what is not working in my 2 solutions?

Comment: I added the container-fluid just as you have suggested, But I don't see any changes

Comment: Hi man, I tried your first solution. turns out it works, thanks for the help. I am really a beginner at this so I didn't know

Answer (score -1):

You have a class of container on there, if you are using bootstrap my advice would be to create your #amethystBackground2 div as an outer div so something like this:

```
<div id="amethystBackground2">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now set your widths/heights accordingly. If you use the overflow-x: hidden rule then you are telling the page that you don't wish to scroll horizontally so scroll bars will not be shown.

Comment: yes it does. I don't have your html  but here is a quick mockup, I'm sure you know how to add buttons to it? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRkBwy