# UX-->UI Responsiveness in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, fixed-width

In bootstrap should the container class be of fixed size?

We want it to display
 the whole width of the desktop and laptop.How can this be tackled.

What if I have custom component how does it stretch to the width of the screen,Should the width be mentioned in percentage?Does the percentage apply to all the elements width?
Please suggest.

Comment: Use `100vw` viewport.

Comment: use <div class="container-fluid"></div>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container

Answer (score 0):

In both bootstrap v3 and v4 you could use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

[Documentation Bootstrap v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

[Documentation Bootstrap v3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)