# how to increase width of right column of header

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, frontend, stylesheet

I am trying to increase the size of the right side of the header because when I write telephone number then it relocate and come to more than one line.

Can you please check it [here](https://shiaziyarat.com/temp/)

Comment: Your question is not solvable without providing related code (part responsible for the `topbar`) in your question.

Comment: Now that you have removed the content behind the link, it becomes even more problematic. You should include the relevant code *in* your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid wrapping, you could use `white-space:nowrap;`. In your case, the phone number is placed in a `span` that has the `call` style. So in your style.css file find the `call` class definition add this style to it:

```
.topbar span.call {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS class 'container' to 'container-fluid' just below the 'topbar div'. It will distribute the available width in a more dynamic way. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container) for the difference between those two styles.