# .Container vs .container-fluid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I use `.container`, the logo is **not going to the left**  but when I use `.container-fluid`, the **logo goes to the left**. please tell me why `.container` is not working.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="project1.html" class="float-left">
            <div id="logo"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: This helps you too . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/container-fluid-vs-container

Comment: Demo or example for this : https://www.jquery-az.com/wwh/demo.php?ex=31.0_1

Comment: Here you go: [container vs .container-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the `.container` has a `max-width` property (1140px in large screen, 960px in medium and so on), but the `.container-fluid` doesn't have `max-width` property it just has `width: 100%`.
p.s please remove `float-left` class, handle it with `flex`