container and container fluid
I want to know that how we know that where to use container or container fluid and also what to do or what to avoid while using container & container fluid ?
need a clear clarity on diiference between container anf container fluid

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/what-is-the-difference-between-bootstrap-container-and-container-fluid-classes

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

container sets a fixed max-width at each responsive breakpoint, while container-fluid sets the width to 100% across all breakpoints, spanning the entire screen viewport.
Read more on this here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#:~:text=Bootstrap%20comes%20with%20three%20different,100%25%20until%20the%20specified%20breakpoint

To use the .container or .container-fluid depends on the layout you want to achieve.
.container:

This class provide a responsive fixed-width container.
This class adjust to different screen sizes with specific breakpoints but maintains a maximum width depending on the viewport or screen size.
You can avoid using this class when you want the content to stretch the full width of the viewport.

.container-fluid:

This class provide a full-width container.
This class adjust to the screen size without any predefined maximum width, allowing the content to take up the entire width of the browser window.
You can avoid using this class when you need a consistent maximum width or when you don't want your content to span the full width of the screen.

For more detail: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-container-and-container-fluid-in-bootstrap-5/

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
