# How to place two containers in bootstrap side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to place two containers side by side, but they are stacked on top of each other. Even container-fluid class doesn't help.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Container Left
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Container Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in Bootstrap?

Comment: may be this will help -- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789954/fluid-container-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid, so each one of your `div`s will take up a row unto itself. You've also placed each one in a row, and rows will always stack. Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            Container Left
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            Container Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that col-lg-6 (left) was not dependant from col-lg-6(right)

Comment: So, is it possible to use two containers side by side somehow?

Comment: This helped me with some parallax scrolling stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can place independent columns next to each other by wrapping your columns in a parent container and flex box. The columns will automatically have equal widths. Here's an example.

**html**

```
<div class="parent-container d-flex">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                Container Left
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                Container Right
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that `container-fluid` is now replaced by `container` http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide but this is not the matter.
Try the `.col-md-offset-*` that moves `*`columns to the right your columns. Check this out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid