# Max width with smaller padding (mixed with laravel and blade)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap 3.  I am designing a page and my content requires more width.  While the menu bar extends out to the sides of the browser, how can I can a bit more width for my content.  I have tried changing container to container-fluid but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the code.  I have 2 files, namely, cc-top-min.blade.php and show.blade.php.  show.blade.php is sucked into cc-top-min.blade.php @content.  http://pastebin.com/gLQc0ADP

Here is a screen shot.  New more width.  WOuld like to extend the content of the page to "almost" as wide as the navbar.  Please help.

[image]

here is the html:  http://pastebin.com/7Q4emw6j

Comment: it's hard to understand what's going on in your pastebin - can you post to bootply or jsfiddle?

Comment: I just added a link to the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this post: [Fluid Container in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789954/fluid-container-in-bootstrap-3). Your navbar extends because it is not wrapped in a .container.

Therefore, you can just omit the .container and start with a row. To narrow it down as you want, add some padding as you see fit.

If container-fluid is not working at all; are you using  bootstrap 3.1 or above as the first one didnt include it: [Container-fluid vs .container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262311/bootstrap-3-1-container-fluid-vs-container)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `container` with `container-fluid` everywhere you've used it. See example: http://www.bootply.com/O7YjWCvRa8